# How do attack bonuses interact with double rolls?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

A half-elf uses **Knack for Success** on a Ranger, who then uses **Split the Tree**:

> **Knack for Success:** The target gains a +2 power bonus to his next
>   attack roll [...]"
>
> **Split the Tree:** Make two attack rolls, take the higher result, and
>   apply it to both targets.

What happens?

1. The ranger rolls one d20 and adds the +2, then rolls the second one and takes the higher result.
2. The dice are rolled at the same time and both gain the +2.
3. The dice are rolled at the same time and the ranger applies the +2 to the higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the case of split the tree it only applies to the first (this is an odd one because you do make *two* attack roles, but use the higher, whereas with say an avenger you roll twice for the attack).

Your first case is what happens in the case of Split the tree. Your second (and third, they're functionally equivalent) case applies in role twice take highest situations.

Comment: Is "roll twice = rolls two dice simultaneously" specified anywhere? If not, it sounds like it could be interpreted as "roll one die, then a second one".